# Touch point X Y differs from X Y of the canvas?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-canvas

I am drawing a rectangle on a canvas with lets say insertion point (5,5) the problem is that when I click on it the touch point is (60,85). I know that the touch point is taken from the whole screen and the rectangle point is taken only from the view part but still the difference is pretty big.

I tried to take the `ImageView` `top()` and `left()` and subtract it from the screen size and still is not working.

Another solution that I tried was to take the invert martix of the `ImageView` and check the coordinates but still the result was the same.

Here is my other approach and still is not working:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView DrawingImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.image2);

    Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
        .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
        .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

   canvas.setBitmap(bitmap2);
    DrawingImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);

    // Draw Rectangle

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    Point insertRec=new Point(5, 110);
    rec.set(insertRec.x, insertRec.y, insertRec.x+25, insertRec.y+20);
    canvas.drawRect(rec,paint);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    imageX=image.getWidth();
    imageY=image.getHeight();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        int x=(int) event.getRawX(); 
        int y=(int) event.getRawY();

        final int index = event.getActionIndex();
        final float[] coords = new float[] { event.getX(index), event.getY(index) };
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        image.getImageMatrix().invert(matrix);
        matrix.postTranslate(image.getScrollX(), image.getScrollY());
        matrix.mapPoints(coords);
        int[] arr = new int[2];

        image.getLocationInWindow(arr);

        int xx=rec.centerX();
        int yy=rec.centerY();

        if(rec.contains(x - arr[0], y - arr[1])){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed a port!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Can someone help me please?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards, Dimitar Georgiev

Comment: Why don't you add an onTouchListener to your ImageView? The coordinates will be correct.

Comment: Well I am still new and I dont really know how to do it.

Comment: I have to make the picture clickable?

Comment: `DrawingImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
   }
  });`

Comment: Unfortunately it has the same result, or I did not implemented it right